# Is there a Rust crate or Cargo upgrade that can format imports?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to optimize and format all crate imports in scope, to clean up the imports sections? The problem is that the imports get crowded and stack up.

Before:

```
use actix_web::web::{Data, Payload};
use actix_web::Error;
use actix_web::{
    error::{BlockingError, ErrorUnauthorized},
    web, HttpResponse,
};
```

After:

```
use actix_web::{web::
                {Data, Payload},
                Error,
                error::{BlockingError, ErrorUnauthorized},
                web, HttpResponse,
};
```

Comment: rustfmt can do that! It does require nightly to merge everything, though.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `rustfmt` can do this. Create a `rustfmt.toml` configuration file in your project directory and specify the following:

```
merge_imports = true
```

The `rustfmt` has [more configurable options](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustfmt/) if you are interested.